# Running DX11 in a browser

Tags: c++, browser, directx

Our engine currently exports C++ code and graphic/data files which we can then compile to PC, IOS, Android, etc. On PC we use DirectX 11. We've now been asked to make it run in a browser, so it can run under Facebook.

So, can we run our code in a browser window without too many changes, or converting all the C++ to HTML? Can we just get some sort of Direct X surface, and the browser will show and interact with it ?

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

In browsers Webgl is probably your best bet.